# electron.clipboard.readText() returns empty string

Tags: electron

I try to use `require('electron').clipboard.readText()` and just get an empty string, although I have some text in the clipboard.

I see this in `Console.app` (not sure if this is related):

```
Failed to set up CFPasteboardRef 'Apple CFPasteboard general'. Error: <error: 0x7fffa6d6fda0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fffa6d70048> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because the Electron app was started via `execve()` in a forked process (`fork() +`daemon()` actually).

One workaround is to execute `/usr/bin/open` as a wrapper, like so (pseudo code):

```
open -a argv[0] --args args[1...]
```

Or basically this code:

```
char** args = parse_args(cmd);
char* arg0 = find_in_path(args[0]);
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    daemon(1, 0);
#ifdef __APPLE__
    {
        // We cannot directly use `execv` for a GUI app on MacOSX
        // in a forked process
        // (e.g. issues like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958926/).
        // But using `open` will work around this.
        int argc = 0;
        for(; args[argc]; ++argc);
        char** args_ext = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc + 5));
        arg0 = "/usr/bin/open";
        args_ext[0] = arg0;
        args_ext[1] = "-a";
        args_ext[2] = args[0];
        args_ext[3] = "--args";
        for(int i = 0; ; ++i) {
            args_ext[i + 4] = args[i + 1];
            if(!args[i + 1])
                break;
        }
        args = args_ext;
    }
#endif
    execv(arg0, args);
    exit(-1);
} else if (pid > 0) { // master
    // go on ...
    free(args);
} else {
    // error handling...
}
```

(Basically via [this commit](https://github.com/PerBothner/DomTerm/pull/58/commits/9556950b3ae37e368cc12851422abbeb767bae51).)